# How to get more word suggestions from Hunspell with pyhunspell

Tags: python, spell-checking, hunspell

I'm using hunspell with the pyhunspell wrapper. I'm calling:

```
hunspell.suggest("Yokk")
```

But this is returning only ["Yolk", "Yoke"]. I saw that "York" is in the dictionary but is not being returned. Is there a way to return more than 2 suggestions, either by increasing the distance threshold or the number of top suggestions?

The text I'm trying to correct is "New York" and I have my own ranker that ranks the suggestions downstream. I just need more suggestions. I tried aspell and by default its returning 10 suggestions, one of which is in fact "York".

Note:
The documentation doesn't mention any other arguments for method `suggest`. Even using the CLI I only get two suggestions:

```
hunspell -d en_US
Hunspell 1.7.2
yokk
& yokk 2 0: yolk, yoke
```

I've checked the default dictionaries are properly loaded using:

```
hunspell -D
SEARCH PATH:
...
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/Library/Spelling/en_US
LOADED DICTIONARY:
/Library/Spelling/en_US.aff
/Library/Spelling/en_US.dic
➜  2 subl /Library/Spelling/en_US.dic
```

And I've also checked that the expected "York" is in the dictionary:

```
cat /Library/Spelling/en_US.dic | grep York
York/M
```

I wonder if there is some other configuration I can set somewhere, I can't see anything evident in either the wrapper or the CLI documentation:
https://github.com/pyhunspell/pyhunspell/wiki/Documentation
https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell

Comment: This package is not maintained last 5 years. It might be just a missing feature there. However, I don't see anything about message count in hubspell own [source](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/fbf0ce7e4737084fe84e733b031634f4a2c7559f/src/hunspell/suggestmgr.cxx#L188). First of all - are you certain that you're using the same dictionaries?

Comment: I am aware this is not maintained but as you mentioned, even the CLI for hunspell only provides two suggestions. Updated my question with this information.